# Best Panorama Jquery plugin for images with this format

Tags: javascript, jquery, panoramas

i need to replace my old FLASH panorama viewer by a jquery/javascript version.

[image]

If you check, you will see that the walls/corners/edges are rounded so you seee it normal when you apply the panorama effect,

the problem is that with all the jquery panorama plugins i get this resutl: http://toniweb.us/m/demos/salleformation.html (the image is only left animated. So the rounded, still rounded)

Do you know any good solution that can work with this kind of images?

PS: what is this format name?

Comment: in the example you provided the image is animated from left to right and it can change directions if you click on the blue button in the left (appears on hover). so it seems to work fine. what exactly do you want it to do?

Answer (score 3):

Did you try also http://jquery.vostrel.cz/reel ? But I fear not a solution for your specific problem.

So you could try this site, carefully reading its stuff: http://webuser.fh-furtwangen.de/~dersch/mp/MotionPanoramas.html

Answer (score 1):

I just came across this plugin. You'll be needing something like this (though it's far from perfect) :

http://code.google.com/p/jspanoviewer/

Comment: Just checking in my phone and cant render demos.. Will see in  the pc

Comment: There are some commercial ones, which do the same, but with multiple images: http://krpano.com/iphone/
http://www.easypano.com/panorama-gallery.html